# Making a Function Pointer With A Base Class as a Parameter and Sending a Derrived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to make a function pointer that takes a parameter of the base class. I want to be able to create a function that pointer can point to but have it take a parameter of the derived class. I then want to be able to call the function parameter with the derived class and have it preform a function as if the parameter was the derived class. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
void(*pointer)(Base);
class Base
{};

class Something : public Base
{
public:
    float f;
    int i;
};

void doSomething(Something s)
{
    //do something
}


int main()
{
    Something s;
    pointer = doSomething;
    pointer(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work in c++?

Comment: What do you mean by "make this work"? You need to be more specific about the behaviour you want.

Comment: Look up _virtual functions_.

Comment: Expanding on @DietmarKühl's advice, you then need to pass the argument by reference (with pass by value, as you currently do, you "slice" the actual argument, copying only its base class part).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I actually meant I wanted to do something else, I updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: @juanchopanza I updated the question to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to paraphrase, you want to have a function that takes a `Base` object parameter, and uses that parameter as if it were actually a derived object.

So basically (psudocode):

```
void DoSomething (Base obj)
{
  obj.DoSomethingWithDerived();
}
```

In order to accomplish this, you need to do two things:

1. Make `Base` polymorphic.
2. Have your function take either a *reference* or a *pointer* to a `Base` -- not a `Base` by value.

### Making Base Polymorphic.

A polymorphic class in C++ is any class that has at least 1 `virtual` method.  In almost every case, you should have a `virtual` destructor anyway (for somewhat different reasons), so all you have to do here is:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base() {};
};
```

### Reference or Pointer Parameter

If you construct a function that takes a `Base` by-value:

```
void DoSomething (Base obj)
```

...and then call it with a derived object:

```
int main()
{
  Derived der;
  DoSomething (der);
}
```

what ends up happening is a *copy of `der`* will be made in the call to `DoSomething`, but the copy won't be a complete copy -- it will only be a `Base` copy.  All of the stuff that's specific to `Derived` will be [sliced away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

So instead of taking a `Base` by-value, you have to take a `Base` either by-reference or by-pointer so that no copy is made:

```
void DoSomething (Base& obj);
```

Comment: How do I then call a function on the Derived Class?

Comment: By providing a virtual method in the base class and overriding it in the derived  class.

Comment: Is there any other way? I want to have the derived class free to be whatever it wants to be. Ex. Store object-specific ints or functions.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing so; however, as far as this function is concerned the object is a Base, so the method you call (at least from this function) has to be known to the Base class.  Your derived class can override that function to do whatever.

Comment: @tabstop So theres absolutely no way to access the specific members of the derived class?

Comment: I'm not quite clear whether you're wanting a "relay function" or not (the "DoSomething" in John's answer above is what I mean -- you're passing that object to that function).  If so, the relay function must treat the object as a Base object.  However, you can call member functions on that object from DoSomething, and those member functions can access all the specific members of the derived class that your heart desires (assuming you've set up the polymorphism as described above).

Comment: @tabstop could I make a method that gives a pointer to the class so in that new method I could call that and get the derived class and use it as such?

Comment: That's basically exactly what John described, but just to be clear I'm going to type up some example code in the big answer box rather than this little comment box and maybe it will be a little clearer?  I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this sample code enlightens.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
        int x;
        virtual void process() {std::cout << "Base: " << x << std::endl;}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        int y, z;
        virtual void process() {std::cout << "Base: " << x << " Derived: ";
            std::cout << y << " " << z << std::endl;
        }
};

void doSomething(Base& bob) {
    bob.process();
}

int main() {
    Derived foo;
    foo.x = 2;
    foo.y = 4;
    foo.z = 6;
    doSomething(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

In doSomething, bob is treated as a `Base` object (so there must be a `process` function in `Base`), but because the member function had been overridden in `Derived`, that definition takes over.